# How to display single image saved in wwwroot/images using ASP.NET Core 7.0 MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-7.0

I am super new to ASP.NET and I'm having trouble displaying a single simple image to the web app.

I have uploaded my image file to `wwwroot/images` and also have set the model and the controller. I also tried simple img src and the image path to it but still the image is not recognized.

The image is not error whatsoever but the web app is not displaying it...

Here is my model:

```
using System;

namespace FirstApp.Models
{
    public class ImageModel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string ImagePath { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Here is my controller

```
public IActionResult DisplayImage(int Id)
{
    var image = new ImageModel
    {
        Id = Id,
        Name = "Image",
        ImagePath = "images/img.jpeg"
    };

    return View(image);
}
```

And here is my `.cshtml` file

```
@model FirstApp.Models.ImageModel

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home Page";
}

<div class="text-center">
    <h1 class="display-4">@Model?.Name</h1>
    <img src="/@Model?.ImagePath" alt="My Image hehehe"/>
</div>
```

Here is my web app

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7PtoX.png)

Any kind of help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: since your load image from local storage use the ~ before the path src="~/@Model?.ImagePath" means the path start from the application's root directory. or add it to your Image model  ImagePath = "~/images/img.jpeg"

Comment: @HezyZiv Hi, I have added the ~ in the cshtml. Somehow the browser only picked up the ~ not the full @Model?.ImagePath. I guess my issue is in the MVC.

Comment: It seems like you your model does not get the correct image. debug your code -> get the image value from your model -> compare with the one that works. or use the browser view source check for the image results from the model

Comment: @HezyZiv Hello, it worked. I accidently passed the controller to Index.cshtml not the file with the same name of the controller action aka DisplayImage. Thank you for your help. Appreciate it a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I test your code, and I can  display single image saved in wwwroot/images, try to check the name of image is same in the ImagePath  like:

```
 ImagePath = "images/flower.PNG"
```

structure:

[image]

result:

[image]

Comment: Hello, thank you for answering. I have triple checked my path. Did you tried my code with the MVC? Or just the normal <img src="~/images/img.jpeg">? I tried the normal one and it worked! I think the issue is my code with the MVC. The inspect from my browser somehow did not identify my Model.ImagePart and Model.Name.

Comment: Hi @AdelaNadhifa ,  Yes , I  tried your code with the MVC. And in the DisplayImage.cshtml file , I  add your  .cshtml file code. " inspect from my browser somehow did not identify my Model.ImagePart and Model.Name." make sure you pass the ImageModel model  from DisplayImage action to the  DisplayImage.cshtml . Besides, I note I have url like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/biue9.png , your image describe don't have.

Comment: Hello yeah, it's on me. Thank you for the explanation. Yesterday I passed the model to Index.cshtml file, not to new DisplayImage.cshtml file. Then I moved the DisplayImage action code to Index action, and it worked in the Index.cshtml.

Why is that? Does the controller action only work with the same name?

But then I still dont have the url like yours. Mine is still in localhost. It only changed to localhost/Home/DisplayImage if I added more navitem to the _Layout.cshtml in Shared folder and access to that. https://imgur.com/zgYWZWi https://imgur.com/7eCvCsw

Comment: Hi @Adela Nadhifa  ,  "Does the controller action only work with the same name?"  If we just use :A model to pass to the view: `return View(image);`  , it does.  It will create a view, add a new file and give it the same name as its associated controller action with the .cshtml file extension. If we  want to pass the model from  DisplayImage action  to the Index view, we need an explicit view to return,both a view and a model:`return View("Index", image);`  .

Comment: Have a look at [Views in ASP.NET Core MVC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/overview?view=aspnetcore-7.0)  to know more.

Answer (score 0):

In your view `(.cshtml)`, you can use the `Url.Content` helper to generate the correct URL for the image in the `src` attribute:

```
<img src="@Url.Content(Model.ImagePath)" alt="My Image hehehe" />
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for answering. I have tried your solution but sadly, it still giving me broken image. Btw, I did try to display the image using normal <img src="~/images/img.jpeg" and it works. I tried to use inspect from the browser to see which part is giving error, and turns out the browser doesn't identified(?) the Model.

Here i copied this from the inspect :
<div class="text-center">
    <h1 class="display-4"></h1>
    <img src="/" alt="My Image hehehe">
</div>

Doesnt identified both ImagePath and Name from the Model.